# Sniffing PPP/WAN interface in Vista/Server 2008

Tags: windows-vista, networking, sniffing

I used to be able sniff traffic on windows xp and server 2003 on PPP/WAN interfaces using wireshark. There used to be a Generic dialup interface, but its seems not to be there on vista/server 2008/7/Server 2008 R2. I did some google but it didnt come up with any results. Have you guys any idea to get it started?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have gathered, wireshark cannot sniff packets across a dialup (PPP/WAN) interface. In short there is nothing that you can do, I've tried to get it to work but it's only for ethernet/wireless interfaces only.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: I guess with Linux same WIRESHARK can do it.